# GitHub rate limits for raw.githubusercontent.com for private repos/orgs

Tags: github, github-pages

I've a private repo under my organisation. I'm playing with the idea of using that repo as content storage for my blog.

Since it's a private repo, I'm sending an authenticated request (with Personal Access Token) to an endpoint like this:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/README.md`

For publicly accessible raw files, the limit is 5000/hr/IP, however I couldn't find any answer for a private repo (there are mentions of API limit but this is different from api.github.com).

Comment: Is there an `x-ratelimit` response header that might give you a clue?

Comment: My guess is that authenticated requests count against the same 5000/h rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no different rate limit for private repositories.  The rate limit for all archive and raw file endpoints (together) is 5000 per hour per IP, regardless of authentication.  In some cases, due to an artifact of how the rate limit works, it may appear to be higher, but that is the rate limit and the value you can safely use.

If you make more requests than that, you'll receive a 429 response, and your IP will be blocked for all HTTPS requests for 30 minutes, so it's recommended that you don't do that.